# array error Missing number, treated as zero. [b,a] Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [b,a] Missing = inserted for \ifdim. [b,a]

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

When i wrote

```
\begin{displaymath}

a\circ b = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}

[a,b] & \textrm{if}~a<b \\

[b,a] & \textrm{if}~ b < a \\
 
\{a\} & \textrm{if}~a = b

\end{array}\right.

\end{displaymath}
```

I get the error messages below, respectively;

> Missing number, treated as zero. [b,a]
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [b,a]
>
> Missing = inserted for \ifdim. [b,a]
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. [b,a]
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [b,a]

What is the reason for this? How can i solve it? Could you please anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `amsmath` package and the `cases` environment. This will allow you to use `\[` to start the equivalent of `displaymath`/`equation*`; also they will allow you to use `\text` to insert text into math formulas (`\mathrm` I think it's best suited for single letters and symbols):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a\circ b = 
\begin{cases}
[a,b]&\qquad\text{if}~a<b\\
[b,a]&\qquad\text{if}~b<a\\
\{a\}&\qquad\text{if}~a=b
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that with the standard definition of `\\`

```
[a,b] & \textrm{if}~a<b \\
[b,a]
```

is the same as

```
[a,b] & \textrm{if}~a<b \\[b,a]
```

so the `[b,a]` is taken as the optional argument so should be a length like `\\[5pt]`. You can use

```
[a,b] & \textrm{if}~a<b \\ \relax
[b,a]
```

to hide the `[` or (better) use the AMS alignments as shown in Moriambar's answer. `amsmath` locally uses a version of `\\` which does not look past end of line when looking for an optional argument.